# Any reason why there is space between elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why there is space between some elements in a design i am working on. the elements in question are the a's: `#gallery li a` I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of the space without using neg margins.

```css
   /* ========== PAGE: GALLERY CSS START ========== */
   #gallery {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
   }
   #gallery li {
     float: left;
     //width: 28.3%;
     padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
     margin: 2.5%;
     background-color: #fdfee6;
     color: #bdc3c7;
     border-radius: 10px;
     border-bottom: 4px solid #bdc3c7;
   }
   #gallery li a {
     display: inline-block;
   }
   #gallery li div {
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0px 5px -3px #000;
   }
   #gallery li a:first-child div {
     border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
   }
   #gallery li a:last-child div {
     border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
   }
   #gallery li a p {
     font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 1em 0;
     color: #384047;
   }
   /* ========== PAGE: GALLERY CSS END ========== */
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- main section start -->
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="background:#ff784f;"></div>
        <p>#ff784f</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="background:lightblue;"></div>
        <p>lightblue</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="background:#11980d;"></div>
        <p>#11980d</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<!-- main section end -->
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3heyxvbg/

Comment: Default behavior of inline-block elements, few ways to deal with it: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space between the elements is the default behaviour of [`inline-block`](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) elements.

To fix it without negative margins:

```
#gallery li a {
  display: inline-block; /* Remove */
  float: left; /* Add */
}
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/3heyxvbg/1/)

**Modified Output:**

```css
/* ========== PAGE: GALLERY CSS START ========== */
   #gallery {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
   }
   #gallery li {
     float: left;
     //width: 28.3%;
     padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
     margin: 2.5%;
     background-color: #fdfee6;
     color: #bdc3c7;
     border-radius: 10px;
     border-bottom: 4px solid #bdc3c7;
   }
   #gallery li a {
     float: left;
   }
   #gallery li div {
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0px 5px -3px #000;
   }
   #gallery li a:first-child div {
     border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
   }
   #gallery li a:last-child div {
     border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
   }
   #gallery li a p {
     font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 1em 0;
     color: #384047;
   }
   /* ========== PAGE: GALLERY CSS END ========== */
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- main section start -->
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="background:#ff784f;"></div>
        <p>#ff784f</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="background:lightblue;"></div>
        <p>lightblue</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="background:#11980d;"></div>
        <p>#11980d</p>
      </a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<!-- main section end -->
```

Comment: Do note that while this may work for simple situations, it may need a "clearfix" to work with more complicated layouts.

Answer (score 1):

The space is due to the `inline-block` element. You can use `float:left` to discard the space between elements. like ..

```
#gallery li a {
  float: left;
}
```

But as it is floating element ,You will not be able to specify the margins of the `ul` element to position it according to your design.
To overcome this you have to add `overflow:auto;` in its parent div.

There is another solution if you want to use `display:inline-block`.
You just have to put some negative margin in the `li` elements. like this..

```
#gallery li a {
  display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
}
```

Although use of negative margins are not good practice. But you can use negative margins in some specific cases like this situation.

Comment: because, as far as i am aware, this is not a bug, just normal behavior the neg margin would only have to be `-4px` this might need to be changed due to font size but at least in this problem it is `-4px`. I wanted a way without neg margins cus that way breaks in IE6&7

Comment: then use `float:left;` . But use `overflow:auto;` in the parent div to change the margins of the list.

Comment: but wont `overflow:auto;` put scroll bars on the element in some browsers?

Comment: That is `overflow:scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3heyxvbg/2/)

This behaviour is due to your dispaly inline property.

Thus, Remove `display:inline-block` and add `float:left;` instead.

That is, the new CSS for `#gallery li a` would be like

```
#gallery li a {
    float: left;
}
```